# Prove sequence $\frac{5n+1}{n^{5}-2}$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Please can someone help prove that the sequence $\frac{5n+1}{n^{5}-2}$ is convergent from first principles?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given. For $n \geq 2$,

$$\left|\frac{5n+1}{n^5-2}\right| \leq \left|\frac{6n}{n^5-n}\right|$$

Also,

$$\left|\frac{6n}{n^5-n}\right|=\left|\frac{6}{n^4-1}\right|$$

Since, $n \geq 2$ we know that the denominator is positive, so:

$$\left|\frac{6}{n^4-1}-0\right| < \epsilon \iff 6 < \epsilon (n^4-1)$$

$$\iff n^4 > \frac{6}{\epsilon}+1$$

$$\iff n > (\frac{6}{\epsilon}+1)^\frac{1}{4}$$

$$\therefore n>N=max\left\{\left(\frac{6}{\epsilon}+1\right)^\frac{1}{4}, 2\right\} \Rightarrow \left|\frac{5n+1}{n^5-2}-0\right| < \epsilon \mbox{ , so the sequence converges to } 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:-**

$\dfrac{5n+2}{n^5-2}<\dfrac{5n+2}{n^4}<\dfrac{n^2}{n^4}=\dfrac{1}{n^2}\ \forall n\geq6$

**Solution**

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{5n+2}{n^5-2}=5\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n}{n^5-2}+2\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^5-2}=0$

Answer (score 0):

Answer: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{5n+1}{n^5-2}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{5}{n^4}+\frac{1}{n^5}}{1-\frac{2}{n^5}}=\frac{0+0}{1-0}=0$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Note that:

$$0\leq\frac{5n+1}{n^{5}-2}=a_n$$

also by induction show that if $2\leq n$ then $a_{n+1}<a_n$ i.e.:

$$\frac{5(n+1)+1}{(n+1)^{5}-2}=\frac{5n}{(n+1)^{5}-2}+\frac{6}{(n+1)^{5}-2}$$
but by induction

$\frac{5n}{(n+1)^{5}-2}<\frac{5n}{n^{5}-2}$ and $\frac{6}{(n+1)^{5}-2}<\frac{1}{n^{5}-2}$

$a_n$ is bounded by $0$ and decreasing then converges